# Is it a diamond issue in static libraries dependency tree?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linker, static-libraries, static-linking

I have a problem that bothers me. I think I encountered it in the past, but I can't find information about similar issues on the internet.

Assume that I have:

- a 'common' library and two different static libs of it: libcommon1.2.a and libcommon1.3.a.
- an 'extra-common' library that uses libcommon1.2.a and provides a new static lib from it.
- a final app that uses latest 'common' (libcommon1.3.a) and latest 'extra-common' ('common' and 'extra-common' are linked to the app).

If between 'common' v1.3 and v1.2 were added new components only, everything should be fine, right?

If 'common' v1.3 changed the API used by 'extra-common', probably I would get a missing symbol issue while linking 'extra-common' with the rest of app.

If 'common' v1.3 keeps the same API as v1.2, but changes some internals, is it possible to have some crashes in runtime (caused by change in size of objects or maybe by changes of vtable, etc)?

Could you send me some terms that I can google, some scenarios what could cause a runtime crash or some links to articles?  Is such a term like "diamond problem in libraries dependencies"?

I would be grateful for anything.

Comment: I think you would most likely have duplicate symbol. And if it compiles, it should be fine at run time. (assume you are not talking about dll/souce code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The (possible) problem you're describing here isn't that you have a diamond structure in your dependencies, it's that you're using a library (extra-common) that depends on libcommon1.2a, but you're linking against libcommon1.3a instead.  It sounds like you already understand why that might not be safe.

I think the term you're looking for is [ABI: application binary interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface).  It's the elements of compiled code that have to match up between modules that are linked together, such as calling conventions and structure layouts.  ABI is analogous to [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface), but it pertains to compatibility of compiled code instead of source code.  The two are independent of each other: you can break API without breaking ABI (e.g. by renaming a field in a structure), and you can break ABI without breaking API (e.g. by changing the size of a data type, or rearranging the fields in a structure).

If libcommon1.3a is not ABI-compatible with libcommon1.2a, you can't safely use your extra-common library with it.  You'll need to recompile the extra-common component using libcommon1.3a headers.  (If 1.3a is not API-compatible either, you'll probably have to make changes in extra-common too.)